# Is there a way to collapse navbar-right at a different point than navbar-collapse?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I'm creating a fixed-top navbar for a website (Bootstrap 3) and I'm wondering is there a way to collapse the navbar-right before the navbar-form?

My navbar-right has links to 4 sections of the website but the navbar-form (which is the middle bit on my nav atm) has a search box. I've styled the CSS for it to look good on mobile when it's all in the menu, but it's too wide for tablets in portrait. I've changed the breakpoint for the collapse in LESS to tablet but now everything collapses into the menu on the tablet, which isn't ideal.

I'd like to keep the search box on tablet-portrait and just collapse the links into the menu. Is this something you can do with bootstrap's nav component. Or do I need custom JavaScript for it?